# reinterpret_cast with an integer literal is not a constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

The code below does not compile neither in `gcc` nor in `clang`. Both complain that, the `reinterpret_cast` to `int*` is not a `constexpr`.

How can I work-around the problem? Note that I cannot modify the macro `PORT`, as it is defined in a 3-rd party library (`avr`).

```
#include <iostream>
#define PORT ((int *)(0x20))
constexpr int *p = PORT;  // does not compile

int main() {
    std::cout << (uintptr_t) p << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `p` (a) to be `constexpr`, (b) at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, if you cannot modify `PORT` you cannot specify `PORT` as `constexpr`.

A `constexpr` expression cannot contain `reinterpret_cast`. It is undefined behavior. Keep in mind that a c-style cast like `(int*)` is reduced to either `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, in this case, `reinterpret_cast`.

Given your example, I don't see why you wouldn't just use `const`.

```
const int *p = PORT;
```

Comment: Turns out I simplified too much my use case. I have accepted this, but posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174694/reinterpret-castvolatile-uint8-t37-is-not-a-constant-expression